# Fay cannot find package fay-base

Tags: haskell, fay

I want to try compile Haskell code to JS using `fay`.
I ran commands:

```
cabal install fay
cabal install fay-base --lib
export PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH"
fay index.hs
```

And got the following error

```
fay: ghc-pkg describe error:
Timestamp 2023-10-14 14:31:08.098832694 UTC for /usr/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/package.cache
ghc-pkg: cannot find package fay-base

GHC package manager version 8.8.4
using cache: /usr/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/package.cache
db stack: ["/usr/lib/ghc/package.conf.d"]
flag db stack: ["/usr/lib/ghc/package.conf.d"]

CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at src/Fay/Compiler/Packages.hs:74:24 in fay-0.24.2.0-98703ca44274df4d510778718dc3447a91cb5be37cf3a454e0e0c3009bdeb7ee:Fay.Compiler.Packages
```

I'm using Ubuntu, cabal-install version 3.0.0.0 .
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling the fay and fay-base packages:

```bash
cabal update
cabal install fay fay-base --lib
```

Check if the fay-base package is installed correctly by querying GHC's package database:

```bash
ghc-pkg list fay-base
```

If it doesn't show up, there might have been an issue during installation. Try reinstalling specifically:

```bash
cabal install fay-base --lib
```

Comment: Hmm, when I run `ghc-pkg list fay-base` or `ghc-pkg list fay` I see no results: `/usr/lib/ghc/package.conf.d
    (no packages)`...